# Why can't I use the WooCommerce set_total() function outside the payment process?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently having the problem that I need to reset an order in some case completely. For this I'm first refunding the payment without creating a complete refund via the method `wc_refund_payment()`.

If this was successfull, I'm trying to reset the order. First I'm removing all order items:

```
$order = wc_get_order( xxxx );
$order->remove_order_items();
```

After this I wanted to set the total of the order to 0 but from here on all tries failed:

```
$order->set_total(null);
```

I still can see the total of my order which is really strange. So I'm looking now for a clean and good way to reset the done payment completely so that the order is like the same as before the payment? The only thing I want to keep are the notices at the right side.

I know that it sounds strange but this is part of my concept and I've found no other way doing this.

Comment: @jonathan I also tried that, no success.

Answer (score 1):

```
update_post_meta($order_id,'_order_total', '0.00');
```

Tested & works.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you save your changes?
You need to save the order changes with the save() function;

```
$order->save();
```